Disabling comments from a certain user
Once I was really enjoying the Mathematica community. The answers were always quick and helpful, and I enjoyed answering myself.
But now, I am more and more discouraged from using the forum because almost every post of mine gets a comment from a certain user. I like constructive criticism and feedback, but in this case, the comments are almost never helpful. Moreover, they (in my opinion) often seem hostile. I believe I am not the only one who has experienced such comments.
My problem is that, formally, they cannot be classified as abusive or inappropriate, so they can't be flagged.
Therefore, my question is: Would it be possible to disable comments on my posts from a specific user? If not, what would be your recommendation on how to deal with this problem?

see here. I have had similar experiences and taken the advice of more experienced users to firmly ignore such commentary.

my previous comment was only that I have chosen not to respond/interact and to support that your experience is not isolated and that the comments, even if technically not flagrant abuse, have been expressed adversely by multiple users. I think C.E. Is correct that all such comments should be flagged for moderator review. The more challenging aspect is their recurrence despite feedback and even suspension.  Perhaps, flagging and moderator action is the best outcome.

Same: I've had such experiences here as well, and have simply stopped responding to inappropriate and idiotic comments. But I think that restricting comments may not help and may even make things worse in a different channel. Restricting an activity tends to make it grow, while giving it space and letting it run its course tends to make it exhaust itself.

@yarchik FYI: I have flagged a number of pejorative comments with effect of their deletion. I have been subject to abusive down-voting. I have continued to witness others subject to such behaviours. I have, therefore, contacted site to lodge Trust and Safety issue related to Code of Conduct. This is unfortunate but I personally will not tolerate or witness more of this. I have no expectation of significant response. That is not a criticism of site or moderators: just a reflection of difficulty of situation. I have just chosen not to remain silent.  I appreciate this is “just a site” etc.

If the relevant user alluded to in this question sees my previous comment: I provided a rational factual account and refer them to the moderators.


My problem is that, formally, they cannot be classified as abusive or
inappropriate, so they can't be flagged.

A comment is a violation of the code of conduct if it causes harm, even if inadvertently. If you flag (e.g. as unfriendly), please know that it will be considered from a human point of view and that the comment doesn't have to meet any formal requirements.
This user has been asked to change his behavior several times and has even been suspended before. The moderator team will assess what actions to take.

See this

@ubpdqn I deleted the comment. I wish that we could address this user better, suspension is still a possibility. I will at least send him a message.

I am not trying to abuse the flag. However, I am also not going to tolerate such comments that I argue are unfounded and abusive in tone. I will endeavour to not interact at all with user . My answer was a genuine attempt. The comment was failure to understand comment and pejorative.

@ubpdqn I think that the flag was appropriate, absolutely. He was out of line. Even if he had been correct (which he was not), it's still not an acceptable way of saying it. It was good that you flagged it.
